# SQLAlchemy get value from a table if not present in another one

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

i'm trying to do the following:

```
class Property(Base):
  name = Column(String(50))
  default_value = Column(String(50))

class AssociatedProperty(Base):
  property_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('properties.id'), primary_key=True)
  collector_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('collectors.id'), primary_key=True)
  property = relationship("Property", backref="ass_prop")
  value = Column(String(50))

class Collector(Base):
  properties = relationship("AssociatedProperty",
                          cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan",
                          lazy="dynamic",
                          backref="owner")

  def get_properties(self, list_of_names):
     """
     When called from a CollectorA instance i need to get all CollectorA name/value pairs.
     When called from a CollectorB instance i need to get all CollectorB name/Value pairs and when a property name is not present i search in collectorA properties.
     If not present in CollectorA's properties i return the property's default value.
     """

class CollectorA(Collector):
  collectors_b = relationship("CollectorB", backref='owner', foreign_keys="[CollectorB.collector_a_id]")


class CollectorB(Collector):
   collector_a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('collectors_a.id'))
    pass
```

I'm trying to achieve this behavior using the lowest number of queries, but i'm not sure how to do this in an elegant way.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you could left outer join the table

eg

```
select tableA.value 
from tableA
left join tableB on tableA.value = tableB.value
where tableB.value is null
```